# gprof generating only flat profile

Tags: makefile, fortran, gprof

I am profiling a fortran code with gprof. The code uses a c pre processor and mpifort wrapper with aocc (AMD compiler) to compile. I am specifying -pg flag for compilation as well as linking. But the profiling file contains only flat profile and not the call-graph data.What could be the issue?

Comment: What command are you using to call gprof?

Comment: gprof executable-file > profile.txt

Comment: You need to call gprof with the [-g flag](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=g-gprof-command) for call-graph data.